# Prove that $A$ is invertible if $a\ne 0$ and $a\ne b$ (find the pivots or $A^{-1}$):

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that $A$ is invertible if $a\ne 0$ and $a\ne b$ (find the pivots or $A^{-1}$):
$$
      A=  \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & b \\
        a & a & b \\
        a & a & a \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Is it enough to say that as long as nothing in the main diagonal equals $0$ (pivots) and a column or row is not repeated, then the matrix is invertible?

Then the questions asks to find the pivots, aren't the pivots just a? The pivots are the numbers in the main diagonal right?

Comment: I think you have to state what you are or aren't allowed to use. This can be answered by computing determinant of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the pivots, you need to row-reduce:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}a & b & b \\ a & a & b \\ a & a & a\end{pmatrix}
\sim \begin{pmatrix}a & b & b \\ 0 & a-b & 0 \\ 0 & a-b & a-b\end{pmatrix}
\sim \begin{pmatrix}a & b & b \\ 0 & a-b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a-b\end{pmatrix}.$$

Thus $A$ is invertible iff the pivots, namely $a$ and $a-b$, are non-zero.

Your argument, namely to consider the main diagonal of the original matrix, fails for this simple invertible example: $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. The pivots aren't given by the diagonal elements of the original matrix!

Comment: from the information from the question ($a \ne 0$ and $a \ne b$) we can come to the conclusion that this matrix is invertible correct?

Comment: @idknuttin Yes, because the pivots are $a$ and $a-b$. And to say that $a \neq 0$ and $a \neq b$ is to say that $a, a-b \neq 0$.